# Why does c++ strip reference qualifiers from inferred return types, and why doesn't lifetime extension work?

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
template <typename U> U func1(std::function<U()> func2) {
  return func2();
}

const int x = 1;
const int& result1 = func1<const int&>([&x]() { return x; });
// result1 = ??????? (random garbage)
const int& result2 = [&x]() { return x; }();
// result2 = 1
```

It seems rather inconvenient that the lambda by default strips the reference qualifier from the type of x in inferring the return value, sneakily resulting in a reference to a destructed temporary in this case.  Why was this language feature designed in this way?

And why does result2 work, while result1 fails to extend the lifetime of the temporary?

Comment: This is just another artifact of how type deduction works. The return type deduction of lambdas obey rules like `auto`

Comment: You can explicitly specify `const int&` as a return type of lambda to get the same result.

Comment: Scott Meyers Talk "Type Deduction and Why You Care" covers the type deduction topic quite well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU

Comment: @Tobi He also mentions how you'd like to tear out your hair by the end of it. Or something like that :)

Comment: Just as an fyi, you (basically) never want to do this. If your function is already a template, you never want to pass a `std::function` to it. Just do `template <class U, class F> U func1(F f) { return f(); }`

Comment: I guess I could make the function a template parameter.  My initial thoughts were that it would make the code harder to read, as the function signature would then no longer describe what the caller wants to know about F, nor the relationship between F and U, requiring the caller to dig through the implementation to see what F should really be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename U>
U func1(std::function<U()> func2) {
  return func2();
}
```

When you instantiate this template with `U = const int&` you get:

```
const int& func1(std::function<const int&()> func2) {
  return func2();
}
```

Then, you pass a lambda `[&x](){ return x; }` to `func1`.

Here is the thing: according to *8.1.5.4 Lambda expressions* the return type of lambda is deduced as `int`:

> If a lambda-expression does not include a lambda-declarator, it is as
>   if the lambda-declarator were (). The lambda return type is auto,
>   which is replaced by the type specified by the trailing-return-type if
>   provided and/or deduced from return statements as described in
>   10.1.7.4.

It means that `func2` above returns returns a *temporary*.

According to *15.2.6.2 Temporary Objects*:

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function
>   return statement (9.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed
>   at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.

So the returned value of `foo1` is bound to the temporary which is destroyed once

```
return func2();
```

is done.

In the situation with `result2` the lambda still returns a temporary `int`, but the lifetime of the temporary is prolonged until the lifetime of `result2`according to *15.2.6 Temporary Objects* as this case does not fall to any exceptions listed in this section of the standard.

Comment: Slight improvement to the answer would be to note that in particular, reference lifetime extension is not transitive: a reference that binds to a temporary value extends its lifetime. When a reference that binds to another reference that is bound to a temporary, the lifetime of the temporary is only extended as far as the reference it bound to directly, not transitively.